# Combine different commands into one using a conditional

Tags: conditionals, macos, renewcommand

I define the following commands

```
\def\R{\mathbb{R}}
\def\Rd{\R^d}
\def\Rn{\R^n}
```

Is it possible to combine these three commands into one using a conditional?

As an example, I would like `\Rx` to output `\R^x`.

Comment: What you show is likely the easiest way...the commands desired have to be defined and will not define themselves.  One alternate approach might be `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand\Rdefine[1]{\expandafter\def\csname R#1\endcsname{\mathbb{R}^{#1}}}
\Rdefine{d}
\Rdefine{n}
\Rdefine{x}
\begin{document}
$\Rd = \Rn + \Rx$
\end{document}`

Comment: Another alternate approach is `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand\R[1][]{\mathbb{R}^{#1}}
\begin{document}
$\R[d] = \R[n] + \R[x]$
\end{document}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it with some syntactic sugar

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\def\tmp#1{\ifx\relax#1\else
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname R#1\endcsname{\mathbb R^{#1}}%
\expandafter\tmp \fi}
\tmp dnx%<- more letters go here
\relax

\begin{document}
$\Rd \Rx \Rn$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this? Let me know if this is not what you had in mind and I'll update the answer.

I don't think it's easy to define `\R<>` commands without delimiters such as `{}` or `[]`. The following is easier. If you really need `\Rx` instead of `\R{x}`, we can perhaps use a loop to define all of those commands.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}

\NewDocumentCommand\R{m}
{ \ensuremath{\mathbb{R}^{#1}} }

\begin{document}

\R{x}

\end{document}
```